# Typecast problem in WIndow 10 (DWORD and ULONG_PTR in WinAPI)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In Windows 7, VS2012 compiler

```
PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, 0, (DWORD) pContext, &pOverlap->m_ol);
```

the above API call is working fine.

But on Windows 10 and VS2017 compiler, member variables in structure of `pContext` are not accessible.

When we change from `DWORD` to `ULONG_PTR`, it is working fine in Windows 10

```
PostQueuedCompletionStatus(hCompletionPort, 0, (ULONG_PTR) pContext, &pOverlap->m_ol);
```

What is reason for this behaviour?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/postqueuedcompletionstatus) the function takes a `ULONG_PTR` as the third parameter, so maybe the difference is the older compiler let you get away with it and the newer compiler is letting you know you are wrong. I would guess you probably were get a warning of some sort from the compiler.

Comment: Yes - casting ints to pointers is implementation-defined - generally means that you can't (shouldn't) rely on the behaviour. If it's a pointer, use a pointer - if it's an int, then use that.

In a related note, you say that "pContext is not accessible" - in that situation, a void pointer is appropriate.

Comment: @pstrjds Warning? Not necessarily, with the 'old'/32bit compiler, both `ULONG_PTR` and `DWORD` could have been aliases for the same underlying type...

Comment: @Aconcagua - You are probably correct, I was thinking more about the newer compiler would most likely complain, which kind of explains why it is "working different", but showing that it was wrong before but you got lucky.  The unfortunate thing from the documentation side is that although the type is `ULONG_PTR` they named the variable `dwCompletionKey` which following the standard Hungarian notation of the Windows API, I would also have expected the type to be a `DWORD`.

Comment: The problem has been mispresented. The issue is a bug, that's unrelated to the compiler or target OS. See [Getting Ready for 64-bit Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/getting-ready-for-64-bit-windows) to understand your problem.

Comment: @pstrjds: the `dw` prefix indeed _was_ right - the oldest SDK containing that function that I managed to dig up (Windows NT 4.0 SDK) indeed had it as a `DWORD`; probably it was fixed later; indeed, the SDK included with VC++6 already has it as `ULONG_PTR`, so the type was probably fixed at some time between 1996 and 1998.

Comment: @MatteoItalia - Thanks for digging that up, I only have VS2017 and latest Windows SDK at this point (thankfully - I use to work on a project that had a piece that we had to build in VC6 and since there was shared code we had to be careful how we fixed pieces that were shared with that library - i.e. no modern C++ in the shared code, etc). I was thinking there must have been something like that since the related functions all seemed to use the `lp` prefix indicating that a pointer was expected.

Answer (score 8):

<del>Most probably the new build differs not only in Windows version, but you are also compiling for 64 bit, while previously you were compiling for 32 bit.</del>

***Update***: OP has clarified that both builds are 64 bit, but this is easily explained; see below.

That cast to `DWORD` is conceptually wrong even on Windows 7/32 bit. Indeed, the API definition requires a `ULONG_PTR`, which is an unsigned integer type big enough to hold a pointer with no loss of data. As such, it's a 32 bit type when compiling for 32 bit, 64 bit when compiling for 64 bit.

Instead, you are casting your pointer to a `DWORD`; `DWORD` is always a 32 bit unsigned type, so when building for 32 bit Windows everything goes smoothly (pointers need no more than 32 bit to arrive intact on the other side), but on 64 bit Windows you are losing the top 32 bit of your pointer.

Now, this *happens to work even on 64 bit Windows 7*; why?

As explained in the comments, this pointer comes from the heap, and by default on Windows 7 the heap starts providing memory from the "low" portion of the 64 bit address space; hence, unless you are consuming lots of memory, you are going to get always addresses with the top 32 bits to zero, so they are going to survive even with the top 32 bits chopped off.

[This changed since Windows 8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150709-00/?p=45181), as ASLR (enabled by default by the linker when building 64 bit executables) randomizes the position of the heap in the virtual address space, which means that you are going to get pointers with non-zero upper 32 bits, that are going to be maimed badly by the cast to `DWORD`.

Long story short: fix your cast<sup>1</sup> and everything will work fine. Also, in future be always wary of casts from a pointer to an integral type that doesn't end with `_ptr` or `_PTR` - there are good chances that you are doing a mistake.

---

***Notes***

1. Strictly speaking, IIRC the standard requires "passing through" `void *` for these casts to work correctly, i.e. the roundtrip through `uintptr_t` is guaranteed only for `void *` (and maybe `char *`? I'll have to check the standard), so it should be `(ULONG_PTR)(LPVOID)pContext`, if `pContext` isn't a `void *` already. However, this being Win32 I'm pretty sure it's guaranteed to work even without the extra cast.

Comment: DWORD is always a 32 bit unsigned type, so when building for 32 bit Windows everything goes smoothly (pointers need no more than 32 bit to arrive intact on the other side), but on 64 bit Windows you are losing the top 32 bit of your pointer.                            >>>> When built for Windows 7 64 bit OS the DWORD usage worked fine. But Windows 10  64 bit with DWORD usage application crashed at run-time.

Comment: @Nithinsriparambudur: that's just luck; probably on Windows 7 the pointer you passed happened to have all the top bits at zero, so it worked fine. Where does that pointer point to - stack, heap, globals?

Comment: @Nithinsriparambudur: [this is quite precisely your case](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150709-00/?p=45181); from Windows 8 onwards the heap position in the virtual address space is randomized, so it's normal to get allocations from the heap starting way beyond the 32 bit portion of the virtual address space.